# Expected value of Binomial Distribution given a condition

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say I have X is random variable where $X\sim Binomial(n,\theta)$. I also have a random variable Y, which is $Y=aX$ if $(X\le 100)$ and $Y=b-cX$ if $(X> 100)$. Those values $a, b, c$ and $100$ are just random constants. We know that the expected value for $X$ is $E(X)=n\times \theta$.

However, in this case, how can I work out the expected value for $Y$ given those conditions? I stuck at $E(Y)=aE(X)$ if $(X\le 100)$ and $E(Y)=b-cE(X)$ if $(X> 100)$. I do not know how to work out the specific $E(X)$ for each of the condition. Could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "...random constants..." In questions about probability be careful with the term *random*. It can easily be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$Y=aX1_{X\leq100}+(b-cX)1_{X>100}=aX+b-(a+c)X1_{X>100}$$ so that: $$\mathbb EY=an\theta+b-(a+c)\mathbb EX1_{X>100}$$

So it remains to find $\mathbb EX1_{X>100}$.

Also we could go for finding $\mathbb EX1_{X\leq100}$ because we know that their summation is $n\theta$.

That boils down to finding:$$\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{n}kk\theta^{k}(1-\theta)^{n-k}\tag1$$Quite a job, I think.

---

**Edit**:

Suggestion how to find $(1)$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{n}{k}k\theta^{k}\left(1-\theta\right)^{n-k}=n\sum_{k=1}^{100}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\theta^{k}\left(1-\theta\right)^{n-k}=$$$$\frac{n\theta}{1-\theta}\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{n-1}{k}\theta^{k}\left(1-\theta\right)^{n-k}=\frac{n\theta}{1-\theta}P\left(Z\leq99\right)$$
where $Z$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n-1$ and $\theta$.

By Central Limit Theorem: $$\frac{Z-\mathbb EZ}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}Z}}=\frac{Z-(n-1)\theta}{\sqrt{(n-1)\theta(1-\theta)}}\sim U$$where $U$ has standard normal distribution.

So an approximation of $P(Z\leq 99)$ is:$$\Phi\left(\frac{99-(n-1)\theta}{\sqrt{(n-1)\theta(1-\theta)}}\right)$$where $\Phi$ denotes the CDF of standard normal distribution.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help and the comments. In your answer, you wrote $Y=aX1_{X\leq100}+(b-cX)1_{X>100}=aX+b-(a+c)X1_{X>100}$. Can I ask what is the meaning of $1_{X\leq100}$ and $1_{X>100}$? And how can I get from the first to the second equation? Thanks again.

Comment: $1_{X\leq100}$ denotes a random variable that takes value $1$ if $X\leq100$ and takes value $0$ otherwise. Similar story for $1_{X>100}$. The equation rests on the fact that $1_{X\leq100}+1_{X>100}$ is constant and takes value $1$.

Comment: I have edited a suggestion how to find $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just partitioning the expectation by Linearity of Expectation: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y)&=\mathsf E(aX\,\mathbf 1_{ X\leq 100})+\mathsf E((b-cX)\,\mathbf 1_{X>100})\\[1ex]&=\sum_{x=0}^{\min\{n, 100\}} \binom nx ax\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}+\mathbf 1_{n>100}\sum_{x=101}^n \binom nx (b-cx)\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x} \end{align}$$

Unfortunately, there's no easy closed expression for this.

You would either have to use an approximation or computation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.